# Какой метод в WPF срабатывает при смене UserControl в ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

В приложении по клику на разные кнопки меню в ContentControl подгружаются разные вьюшки. В каждой вьюьшке идет запрос к базе данных, каждую секунду в цикле, для обновления данных, получается что при переходе на другую вьюху, в предыдущей продолжает выполнятся метод, какое событие срабатывает при этом?

Это метод который каждую секунду срабатывает во ViewModel

```
CancellationTokenSource ct = null;
```

```
async void DBAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ct == null)
                ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
        }
        if (ct == null)
        {
            break;
        }

        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), ct.Token);
            await Task.Run(() => getDataDB());
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В `ContentControl` при изменении свойства `Content` срабатывает метод [`OnContentChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.oncontentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), но к сожалению не существует стандартного события `ContentChanged`, на которое можно было бы подписаться и узнавать таким образом об изменениях View внутри `ContentControl`.

Но никто не мешает вам определить это событие самостоятельно:

```
public class CustomContentControl : ContentControl
{
    public delegate void ContentChangeEventHandler(object sender, ContentChangedEventArgs e);

    public static readonly RoutedEvent ContentChangedEvent
        = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
            nameof(ContentChanged),
            RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(ContentChangeEventHandler),
            typeof(CustomContentControl));

    public event ContentChangeEventHandler ContentChanged
    {
        add => AddHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value);
        remove => RemoveHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value);
    }

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        var ea = new ContentChangedEventArgs(ContentChangedEvent, this) {NewContent = newContent};
        RaiseEvent(ea);
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
    }
}

public class ContentChangedEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
{
    public object NewContent { get; set; }

    public ContentChangedEventArgs() : base() { }
    public ContentChangedEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent) : base(routedEvent) { }
    public ContentChangedEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent, object source) : base(routedEvent, source) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз ваш метод выполняется в VM, ему не стоит знать о том, что есть во View. Ваш код должен по идее быть организован так:

1. По клику на кнопки вызывается через Binding команда в «большой» VM.
2. У вас в VM есть свойство `ActivePart`, отвечающее за текущую активную «маленькую» VM, и список этих самых «маленьких» VM. Вызванная команда вызывает у активной маленькой VM метод `Deactivate`, присваивает `ActivePart` новую маленькой VM из списка, и вызывает у неё метод `Activate`.

   - Для этого все маленькой VM должны имплементировать общий интерфейс, или быть порождёнными от общего базового класса.
3. В методе `Activate` VM запускает метод наподобие `DBAsync`, а в методе `Deactivate` останавливает его. Для этого проще всего завести в маленькой VM поле `bool flag`, цикл `while (true)` поменять на `while (flag)`, и при необходимости оборвать цикл просто устанавливать `flag = false;`.